# Should I use different key for each column?

Tags: java, encryption

I am working on encryption of my database. I have multiple columns, that I want to encrypt.I am using AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding cypher in Java.

Now, the question is, should I use different key for each one of them, or should I just use one key for all columns?

Comment: Where are the keys stored?  If you chose to encrypt with different keys and then stored all the keys in the same place, then you might as well only encrypt with one key.  And don't use ECB, that is pretty much the first (or second) rule of block ciphers.

Comment: @LukePark, I use server side encryption, so all of the keys will be available in the server. What should I use in place of ECB?

Comment: Not much point in encrypting at all then.  Encrypted data stored along side the encryption key is, for all intensive purposes, just plaintext.  And you should use GCM if you can.  If not, use CBC and authenticate it with an HMAC.

Answer (score 3):

Use as many keys as there are are intersecting roles which require access to that data.

Should a table (for a multi user password manager) look like this:

- Username
- Password

Then your system should be able to provide a key to decrypt the Username, but only the user should be able to provide a key to decrypt the Password. For that schenario you need 2 keys.

To complicate this; should both the system, the user and possibly other users be able to provide keys to decrypt the password, then you need to  have the password in two or more different columns which will arguably (altough not technically) lead to a situation in which you cannot have 3NF database design.

Comment: Except the password would never be decrypted at all because it would be hashed and not encrypted.  Or at least it should be.

Comment: @LukePark I had a password manager in mind, in which users must be able to retreieve their passwords. For a login-to-website scenario, your comment is correct. I have edited my reply to reflect this, thank you for pointing this out!